# Launch my App on navigating inside my website

Tags: android, hyperlink, deep-linking

I have my web app and mobile app. If I click on link for my website from anywhere (Notepad, SMS) in my mobile device, it asks me to open the link in app or Chrome.

But if I click any link inside my website, it doesn't ask to open in app or Chrome. It just navigates to web page in Chrome.

Suppose I have the app installed in my device and I opened my website on chrome browser in my device. Now when I click any link on my website, the android OS should ask me whether to open tgis link in app or in chrome. This is my desired behaviour

How I can achieve the desired behaviour from Chrome?

Comment: I can't tell from your question what your actual desired behaviour is.

Comment: Suppose I have the app installed in my device and I opened my website on chrome browser in my device. Now when I click any link on my website, the android OS should ask me whether to open tgis link in app or in chrome. This is my desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the App/Deep Linking documentation?

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html